# Sending Serial commands to NEC IP phone

Tags: ip, ethernet, serial-communication

Does anyone know if it's possible to send serial commands to NEC DT300 IP phone?
The phone is connected to the the intranet with ethernet wire. There is also an a USB port which I'm not sure the function of.

Thanks in advance,
Cuitino

Comment: According to the manual, the USB port can be used to control the phone (dial up, answer,...) from a computer using a specific software. You are best positioned than anybody to tell how. What happens when you connect the phone to a computer? Is it asking for a driver? You should check what kind of device you get on Device Manager

Comment: Interestingly enough nothing happens when i connect the phone to the computer. It's not asking for any drivers. The windows device manager remains unchanged. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the phone switched on? Any USB device should give you a prompt for a driver and show on device manager, unless it's disabled (some devices have a port that can only be used to update its firmware or troubleshooting by their factories or personnel only)